# List of tables in a database that includes the first row from all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to combine the results of these 2 queries:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etYZF.png)

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @sql = @sql+'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM '+'['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'+';'
FROM sys.tables 
ORDER BY name ASC
EXEC(@sql);
```

**Sample Output:**

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhq5H.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApdWF.png)

[Table3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB1Ue.png)

[Table4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9CPA.png)

**Desired Output:**

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRWOx.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Your desired results' [Sample] column includes sample values for many different datatypes. I'm gonna give it an nvarchar(max) datatype which should cover through explicit conversion most datatypes.

Disclaimer: Did this in blind, might have errors

First, put your first query result in a table. We will be using dynamic sql on the next part, so it cant' be a #table- use either a [normal table] or a ##table:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
into ##a
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

Now add your [sample] column:

```
alter table ##a add [Sample] nvarchar(max)
```

Now, you'll have to make different dynamic queries. You'll need a cursor for that:

-- First, declare one variable for each column the cursor needs. And the sql one

```
declare @table_name sysname, @column_name sysname
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
```

-- Now the cursor stuff

```
declare column_cursor cursor static local for
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
    from ##a
    
open column_cursor
while 1=1 begin
    fetch next from column_cursor into @table_name,@column_name
    if @@fetch_status<>0 break
set @sql='update ##a set [Sample]=convert(nvarchar(max),top1_query.datum)'
    +'from ##a'
    +'cross apply (select top 1 ['+@column_name+'] as datum from ['+@table_name+']) as top1_query'
    +'where ##a.TABLE_NAME='''+@table_name+''' and ##a.COLUMN_NAME='''+@column_name+''''
    exec(@sql)

end -- while
close column_cursor

deallocate column_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can construct a dynamic query which will take the first row of every table and unpivot it.**

You need double aggregation here, once for the columns, and again for all the tables

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT TOP (1)
    TABLE_NAME  = ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ',
    v.*    
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
' + c.cols + '
) v(COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, SAMPLE)'

-- you can add ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID()) here if you want to get a random row

    AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
'    )
FROM sys.tables t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
        '(' + QUOTENAME(c.name, '''') + ', ' + QUOTENAME(typ.name, '''') + ', CAST(t.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' AS nvarchar(max)))'
         AS nvarchar(max)), '
,')
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.types typ ON ON typ.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
) c(cols)
);

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```